# How to Find Img Tags Having src null. and deleting it

Tags: javascript, image, src

I need to delete or hide the Img tag or its parent when Img have src="".

I have a script but it is not working..

```
window.onload=function(){
   var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
   for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
    {
        var img = imgs[i];
        if(img.src==""){
         img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
        }
    }
}
```

Its is not finding the img having scr="". while in IE and Safari is is showing cross sign ( Red ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user jQuery for that :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("src") == null || $(this).attr("src") == '')
         {
             $(this).remove();
          }
    });
});
```

The workaround is set the style of the div container where there is the news as display:none; then once th for each loop is executed you set the div as visible.

here you have a code mockup..

```
 //html (iframe content)
 <div id="newsContainer" style="display:none;">
 </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("src") == null || $(this).attr("src") == '')
         {
             $(this).remove();
          }
    });
    $("#newsContainer").show();
 });
```

Comment: thanx for reply.. i m implementing this

Comment: Hey David.. thanx for reply. I worked for me. I will mark this as answer. But i need more specific answer. I have an .asp and i have iframe in this and this iframe is populated with news and images. Iframe is using a html page. I put this code on html page. but scene is firstly IE is showing RED cross sign and after all the page has laoded, it removes img tag. I applied the my script on <img> tags onload event, but it didnot worked. any help on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery to add in functionality that will make this cross-browser compliant without going bonkers. Your code would end up looking like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img[src='']").remove();
});
```

Comment: Not the one that downvoted, but while jQuery may be javascript, javascript isnt jQuery.

Comment: Everyone uses jQuery for everything these days. Not that I don't like jQuery myself, but this indicates something is seriously wrong with both the way JS is implemented (cross-browser compliance!?) and the feature set of client-side JS. Too many simple tasks need a 24,000 character (guess) library. Pushing all that functionality into client-side JS would be as much work as all the JS interpreter optimalization they're doing now, but would result in less traffic...

Comment: Thanx for reply..  i need to put it on on ready event.. m i right

Comment: So I got a downvote because of how poorly javascript is implemented in browsers?

Comment: You already selected an answer, did that other guy not answer the question? Then you need to uncheck it or we don't know to keep helping you.

Comment: I just checked my answer above, assuming that your empty src img tags actually look like <img src=''> then it works, but if your src does not exist at all it would need something else. Yes, you do need the document.ready() stuff.

Comment: @@ C Bauer.... Thanks for helping me. I chose that as answer because I implemented above solution and it gave what i exactly wanted. I am not saying that your answer is wrong. but i edited my question at the end.

Comment: @Anil - Sorry I think that elipsis (...) mean something different where I come from, I thought you were indicating that you still needed help on this issue when you said "thanxx guys.....". Cheers!